# What is the difference between two connect styles in Qt?

Tags: python, qt

We can use old syntax, like this

`connect(sender, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QString, QString)), receiver, SLOT(updateValue(QString));`

And new one, like this

`connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);`

New syntax allows us to see errors with `connect` on compile time, which is a plus, but is there another differences? I can recall I saw something about it, but can't recall or find it.

Comment: It's slightly faster because it does not need a string lookup (see the generated moc file for it). See also https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html and https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work-part2-qt5.html for a in-detail description on how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chehrlic for articles about this question. In summary, differences between these two approaches are:

1. Compile-time check. You can't compile application until all `connect()` will be used correctly.
2. Arguments automatic type conversion. New syntax allow us not to worry about implicit conversions, e.g. `QVariant` can be used as `QString`.
3. Usage of С++ lambda expressions. You can connect lambda expressions, if you wish so.
4. You can use not only `slots` to be receivers of the `signals`, but any function or functor.